# Find functions $f$ and $g$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ such that  $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f-g)(x)=0$$.Can you find such fuch function with $g(x)\gt 0$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

Justification:I guess there do not exist such functions because for $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f-g)(x)=0$$ then it says that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=L\ne 0$$ and if it so then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1\ne 0$$ which is contradiction.hence there do not exist such functions which satisfies given condition.
    I am not sure about my justification.Is it correct?Please help me.

Comment: I believe your logic is okay, although I think there are some assumptions with assuming $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$ but I do not remember them.

Comment: I tried many examples but most of them are failed to satisfy all the conditions specially  $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f-g)(x)=0$$ and  $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f/g)(x)=0$$

Answer (score 5):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\big(f(x)-g(x)\big)=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$ imply $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}=0$, i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.